# Show page after specific Javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont want to reveal html page content if one specific javascript is not fully loaded. I want to show blank page when this javascript is loading. Javascript is located in .js file, so in html page it looks like this:

```
<script src = "file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tag into the `head` element of the html document, e.g.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="file.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually javascript is inside <head> tags, but it's script take some time to run completely, so i want to hide page meanwhile it is not fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether file.js performs asynchronous operations.

If your file contains simple, synchronous code, a hackish solution would be to put `document.body.style.display="none"` at the start of the code and `document.body.style.display="block"` at the end. This will hide your document body until the script reaches the end.

A more robust solution would be to make sure all your code is in appropriate functions, and wrap the initial function with a callback that displays the body.

```
window.onload = runOnLoad( function() { document.body.style.display="block"; } );

function runOnLoad( callback ) {
    document.body.style.display="none";
    // rest of your code
    callback();
}
```